# Cannot create POSIX named semaphores due to a permissions error (EACCES)

Tags: c, posix, solaris

This is a tough one.

Cannot create a POSIX named semaphore (`sem_open`) no matter the name on a system where there are no semaphores (thus no chance of name overlapping). This is a non-privileged user able to create a shared memory using shmget.

**Platform**: Solaris 10

**Hardware**: Intel Xeon E5000 series CPU

Does not happen on other Solaris 10 platforms running AMD CPUs with non-privileged users. Does not happen on Linux machines. No apparent differences between these machines, other than the fact that this machine is very likely virtualized.

Code:

```
    const char* name = "/permission_test_semaphore";

    sem_t* sem = sem_open(name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 0);
    if (SEM_FAILED == sem)
    {
            printf("Could not create test semaphore %s, errno = %d\n", name, errno);
    }
```

Output is:

```
Could not create test semaphore /permission_test_semaphore, errno = 13
```

Any ideas are welcome -- my hopes are not up.

Comment: ipcs has nothing to do with POSIX sems. It's for legacy sysvipc.

Comment: Correct -- double checked that. Took out the reference to `ipcs`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that security or resource-limiting settings are preventing it.  I'd look through http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/821-0182/fxxtz/index.html for ideas on that.

Comment: Good lead. Unfortunately, there are no differences for `prctl $$` compared to the working Solaris machines, e.g. `prctl -n process.max-sem-ops $$` yields the default values.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, /dev/shm must exist for POSIX shared memory and semaphores. I suspect Solaris needs something similar.

Comment: The other Solaris machines do not have anything on `dev/shm` and creating semaphores just works.

Comment: I confirm that on the working Linux machines `/dev/shm` is set up.

Comment: Did not know about `strace`, but it did not work (unable to open /dev/log). However, googling, I found `truss`, which showed a system access to `/tmp/.SEMLpermission_test_semaphore`, where my user does not have permissions. Apparently, `sem_open` on Solaris creates a file by the name of `/tmp/.SEML<name>` -- how weird and undocumented is that...

Comment: Not so undocumented, actually -- if one read this book (Solaris Internals, Core Kernel Architecture) it would be plain obvious -- http://books.google.com/books?id=r_cecYD4AKkC&lpg=PA454&ots=oCueg2AGyR&dq=sem_open%20sunos%20creates%20a%20file%20in%20the%20%2Ftmp%20directory&pg=PA454#v=onepage&q=sem_open%20sunos%20creates%20a%20file%20in%20the%20/tmp%20directory&f=false

Answer (score 0):

The reason is no permissions in the `/tmp` directory. The SunOS implementation for creating POSIX named semaphores requires creating files in the **hardcoded** `/tmp` path. This is documented in the *SOLARIS Internals, Core Kernel Architecture* book, page 454:

> The POSIX semaphore code uses the **/tmp** file system for the creation and storage of the files that the code memory maps based on the argument passed in the **sem_open**(3R) call.

Running `truss <executable>` will show access to `/tmp/.SEML<sem_name>` right before giving the on-screen error.